# Cannot load main class in swing explorer

Tags: java, swing, jar, robotframework

I have been stuck in below problem for long time I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/robotframework/SwingLibrary/wiki/Getting-Started).

I put  swinglibrary-1.8.0.jar, swexpl.jar, and swag.jar file in a directory. Then I set my classpath to

```
CLASSPATH=.;%PSSFolder%\PSS.jar;%PSSFolder%\swinglibrary-.8.0.jar;%PSSFolder%\swag.jar;%PSSFolder%\swexpl.jar;%PSSFolder%\swinglibrary-1.8.0.jar
```

Where `%PSSFolder%` is the path to the folder

Then I cd to `%PSSFolder%` and execute below

```
java -cp swexpl.jar:swag.jar:swinglibrary-1.8.0 org.swingexplorer.Launcher org.robotframework.swing.testapp.examplesut.TodoListApplication
```

I end up getting

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.swingexplorer.Launcher

I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses semicolons to separate classpath items.  Try replacing the colons with semicolons:

```
java -cp swexpl.jar;swag.jar;swinglibrary-1.8.0 org.swingexplorer.Launcher org.robotframework.swing.testapp.examplesut.TodoListApplication
```